# How to assign full permissions to a folder on portable hard drive?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am unable to start the MySQL service and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880044/unable-to-restart-mysql-after-changing-the-datadir) answer, which requires assigning `Full Control` permissions for the data folder, but my data folder is on a portable hard drive and doesn't have a Security properties page.

[image: Screenshot]

How do I resolve this?

Comment: To elaborate on @jim-diroff-ii's answer, exFAT doesn't support ACLs, whereas FAT32 and NTFS do, with the latter being preferable to the former since FAT32 doesn't support ACLs on removal drives. It's unlikely `Full Control` permissions are the issue with exFAT, as all users, groups, and services have full access to exFAT since it lacks ACL support, and instead the issue is likely that everyone has full access when everyone should not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Security tab only shows for removable drives if the drive is NTFS. Reformat to NTFS and then you should be able to give the appropriate permissions.

Comment: To elaborate on this, exFAT doesn't support ACLs, whereas FAT32 and NTFS do, with the latter being preferable to the former.

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks for the additional information. I just tested this for my own sake, and when formatting a removable disk to FAT32 or exFat, there was no security tab, only when formatted to NTFS. Perhaps you can only apply an ACL to an internal FAT32 disk?

Comment: You're right, I didn't realize that =]